# Initializing an array with unknown size in c/c++

Tags: c++, c

When using C++, I happened to find that I can initialize an array which size is determined by the integer I input when running.
I heard that C99 allows that. In compilation, it doesn't determine the size of the array. It realocate the memory in stack to the array in run. I want to find how it is implemented.
I also heard that C allows that. It is also a example that C++ cannot cover all of the C. Is it true?

Comment: You should point your attention on pointers, especially in C. Your problem is solved dynamically allocating memory based on your array's size

Answer (score 5):

Use `std::vector` in C++. The storage of the vector is handled automatically, being expanded and contracted as needed.  You should avoid the usage of array if not explicitly required, which I don't think is true for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Variable length arrays are only available in C, not in C++.

You should use dynamic arrays or std::vector.

```
size = 17;
int* cxxarray = new int[size];
int* c__array = malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
std::vector<int> vector(size);
cxxarray[7] = 8;
c__array[7] = 8;
vector[7] = 8;
delete[] cxxarray;
free(c__array);
// no need to free vector
```

Comment: `alloca()` is not part of standard C nor is is part of standard C++.   It is a vendor specific function.   Also, it is usually strongly preferable in C++, since it is safer, to use a standard container (like `std::vector`) to manage dynamlcally allocated arrays, rather than using operators `new` and `delete` directly - the way you have presented it implies operator `new` is the better way, and vector a minor alternative.

Comment: The OP is obviously referring to VLAs.

Comment: @Ludin I'll edit the answer

Comment: Thanks. But some IDE actually apply this to C++. For example, Clion. ` int n;`` cin >>  n``int a[n];` is legal in practice.

Comment: @Running Noob Of course a compiler can do whatever it wants, but then you depend on that compiler.